# Script to randomly pick from a list if cells match specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Looking for a basic script that will trigger if cell A1 AND B1 contain a specific text, it will return a value (name) from a random pool of entries and display it in cell C1. My goal is to create a chart, pick to values in A and B and depending if specific values match, pick a random entry from a list and display it in C.

I was trying RANDBETWEEN + CHOOSE which technically works, but every other action in the spreadsheet will automatically generate a new random and re-trigger all the randoms, altering the whole list (since it's volatile) which I don’t want to happen, I’m open to suggestions from any other formulas that might work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: to make your question on-topic include existing code (javascript) you tried and what is failing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to restrict re-evaluation of random functions only when specific cells are edited. Namely:

1. Create another spreadsheet, call it S2 to distinguish from the original spreadsheet A1
2. In S2, enter `importrange` referring to a cell or range of spreadsheet S1
3. Also in S2, enter any random number formulas you need: `rand`, `randbetween`, etc.
4. Back in S1, enter `importrange` that imports the output of those random formulas.

Result: the random values will get re-calculated only when the range of S1 in item 2 changes. Entering data elsewhere in S2 will not trigger recalc.

---

A script is a possible solution, but takes more work: you'd need to use the [`onEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) trigger to run a function on every edit; the function would need to check if the edit

Answer (score 0):

Custom functions are only recalculated when their arguments change. You could use this feature to prevent that the result changes.

To force a recalculation you could

1. Delete and reenter the formula
2. Use a *control* argument that you changes every time that you want that the formula result be recalculated.